# How to avoid Unknown: write failed: No space left on device (28)

Tags: php, image, temporary-directory

I am on a shared host and i get this error on my domain

```
Unknown: write failed: No space left on device (28)
```

I think its because my /tmp directory is full, but i can't be sure. If that is the case can anyone help me why this is happening? It is the second time this happens and I have to take my site off the web when it does, which is not good...

I don't know if it is related, but I handle a lot of images and convert them in PHP. I save them temporary using the `tempnam()` function. Is this causing the error?

Do anyone have any idea?
Please I really need to fix this fast :(
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can have two reasons:

- Your web hosting account has a quota set, which you have exceeded. Solution: Free up some space. (You should have some sort of control panel that can give you an indication whether this is the case.)
- The web server your site runs on has run out of space. You need to talk to your hosting provider. They need to make sure this doesn't happen again.

Comment: yes they have set a quota. But I don't think that I can free it in the admin-panel... Do you know what is causing this problem?

Comment: @Mathias yes, one of the things mentioned should be causing it. If you're above your quota, you need to delete some files - but I'd make sure whether that really is the reason first

Comment: The host have raised my quota once before, and that fixed the problem. I can't clean my tpm-dir from the acp... But how do i process images in PHP if I can't use the tmp-dir?

Comment: @Mathias you'll need to speak to your hosting provider. This could also be a global problem on their end. Impossible to tell... if it's *your* personal quota, deleting some unused files (no matter which directory they are in) would help.

Comment: ok thanks. I have written an email to the hosting provider asking them for a solution. I just hope they will answer soon :) Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: i can't flush the tmp-directory with a script? It has to be done by the administrator?

Comment: @Mathias it wouldn't make sense, it will get flushed anyway sooner or later. Let the admin tell you what the problem is. If it's your personal quota, solve it by ordering more space or deleting some files